# Can the 50,000 free MAUs in Azure AD B2C be used with a free Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

From the Note in [this section of the Azure AD B2C doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing#about-the-monthly-active-users-mau-billing-model), it sounds like one can't use the free tier with a free Azure subscription. On the other hand, there's a number of online discussions where a Microsoft employee confirms that the free tier can be used with a free subscription. For example [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/667158/azure-ad-b2c-with-free-subscription-actual-cost).

**Which is it?**

Context: I want to learn Azure by building a customer-facing SPA (preferably using LinkedIn as social identity provider if that matters). Not that I expect much traffic, but I'd rather stay clear from any risk of getting billed. And before I start coding, I want to understand what can be done with the "always free" services that comes with the free subscription.

Thanks!

Comment: The first article just stated the b2c tenant need to be link to a subscription. Have you tried creating a new b2c tenant ? Also if just for learning purpose you probably wanna have a look at Microsoft Entra External ID: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/faq-customers#is-microsoft-entra-external-id-a-new-name-for-azure-ad-b2c

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I haven't tried, as I'm not sure how I to verify that the b2c tenant gives me 50k MAU for free once tied to the subscription. I don't think Entra External ID can use LinkedIn as identity provider, which is why I was considering AD B2C instead.

Answer (score 0):

I created a B2C tenant with a handful of users and linked it to an Azure subscription. I built a SPA to test user flows, exactly like you're proposing to do. I've had it live for a few months and have not been billed at all for it.

Your mileage may vary. No one on this site is going to go on record with billing questions. Microsoft (they all do this though) prefers that billing expectations are ambiguous.